# If, elif, else conditions

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean

I was dealing with CodingBat problems to learn better and more efficiently and the problem I've faced was:

```
Given 2 int values, return True if one is negative and one is positive. Except if the parameter "negative" is True, then return True only if both are negative.


pos_neg(1, -1, False) → True
pos_neg(-1, 1, False) → True
pos_neg(-4, -5, True) → True
```

I wrote that code to run the desired process

```
def pos_neg(a, b, negative):
  if (a<0 and b>0) or (a>0 and b<0):
    return True
  elif negative and (a<0 and b<0)
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

but I get

```
Compile problems:


invalid syntax (line 4)
```

as an Error.
Solution given by CondaBat is:

```
def pos_neg(a, b, negative):
  if negative:
    return (a < 0 and b < 0)
  else:
    return ((a < 0 and b > 0) or (a > 0 and b < 0))
```

I see that the example code given by is faster and more efficent compared to mine but I can't see why my elif statement returns an error.

Comment: It's missing a semicolon at the end of the `elif` line.

Comment: I need a sleep I suppose

Comment: Shorter: `return a < 0 and b < 0 if negative else a * b < 0`

Comment: Note that your code is not logically equivalent to the example.

Comment: @molbdnilo: `a * b < 0` can be replaced with `(a < 0) ^ (b < 0)`. Sure, slightly longer, but describes the goal more directly, and since`bool`s with bitwise operators still produce `bool`s, not `int`s, it works as expected. This approach avoids the need to compute potentially enormous products just to check the sign of the inputs. You could also change `a < 0 and b < 0` to `(a < 0) & (b < 0)` to match, but you'd only do it for symmetry; there's no real performance or readability benefit to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your are missing a colon after elif

```
def pos_neg(a, b, negative):
  if (a<0 and b>0) or (a>0 and b<0):
    return True
  elif negative and (a<0 and b<0): # <- was here
    return True
  else:
    return False
```

Comment: Feel so silly right now, thank you very much